# Add an object to the array using interaction between elements in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

So what I'm trying to do basically is to implement a shopping cart using JS and Polymer features.

Here are my elements (simplified).

**shop-cart**

```
<template>
  <div class="shoppingMainContainer">
    <div class="cartTitle">Cart</div>
    <paper-dialog-scrollable>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{shoppingList}}">
        <div class="shoppingItem">
          <div class="itemName">{{item.name}}</div>
          <div class="itemDivider"></div>
          <paper-input value="{{item.quantity}}" max="99" min="1" auto-validate allowed-pattern="[0-9]" label="num" class="itemQuantity" no-label-float type="number">
          </paper-input>
          <div class="itemDivider"></div>

        </div>
        </template>
    </paper-dialog-scrollable>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="cartActions">
      <paper-button on-tap="_clearShoppingList" id="clearCartButton">Clear all</paper-button>
      <paper-button id="checkoutButton">Checkout</paper-button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </template>


</dom-module>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer ({
        is: "shop-cart",


    ready: function(){
      this.shoppingList = [



      ];
    },

    _clearShoppingList: function() {
      this.shoppingList = [];
    },


  });
</script>
```

**product-card**

```
<template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{productsList}}">
        <paper-card
        elevation="1"
        id="{{item.id}}"    
        class="white">
        <div id="cardHeader" class="header style-scope paper-card">
          <iron-image class="cardImage" sizing="contain" src="{{item.image}}"></iron-image>
          <div id="miniHeadeText" class="title-text over-image style-scope paper-card">{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="description">{{item.content}}</div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-actions">
          <paper-icon-button on-tap="_addToCart" icon="icons:add-shopping-cart"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-button class="open-button" noink">Details</paper-button>
        </div>
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
      </paper-card>
      </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer ({
        is: "product-card",




     ready: function(){
      this.productsList = [{
        "id": 0,
        "name": "1",
      },{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "2",
      },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "3",
      },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "4",
      },{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "5",
      },{
        "id": 5,
        "name": "6",
      }];
    },




  _addToCart: function(event) {
    this.fire("addItem",this.productsList[event.model.item.id]);
  }

    });
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
(function (document) {
    document.addEventListener('addItem',function(data){
      document.querySelector('shop-cart').shoppingList.push(data.detail);
    })
}
```

*_addToCart* method should add an object to the shoppingList (which belongs to shop-cart) with properties taken from specific product-card element. 
I have no idea why it doesn't work. If you can point out a mistake in my code to me or (even better) come up with better implementation of this concept, please do.

Thanks.

Comment: Here are few ideas:1) Wrap them both in parent element and using `polymer binding` to pass data between them.2) Use `iron-signal` to pass data between them. 3)Use `iron-metadata` to pass data between them. 4)You can also use `local` or `session storage` to pass data. 5) Best option would be to use `API`. I have not tried your code but i'd suggest try `this.push` instead `shoppingList.push`

Answer (score 1):

Changes that imperatively mutate an **object** or **array** are not observable. If you have a simple property like:

```
this.name = 'Jane';
```

Polymer will automatically create a *setter* and it will automatically pick up any changes on that property. However, changes on an object subproperty or an **array** (like your shoppingList) will not work:

```
this.users.push({ name: 'Andre'});
```

Using native Array.push doesn't invoke the setter on users, so it isn't automatically observable.

In the case of object subproperties:

```
this.address.street = 'Elm Street';
```

The setter on address will not be called and the change will not be detected as well.

Polymer provides specific methods for making observable changes to subproperties and arrays, in the example above you would need to call:

```
this.set('address.street', 'Elm Street');
```

And in the case of arrays:

```
this.push('users', { name: 'Andre'});
```

In your specific case, you should change your *app.js* to make sure the changes to the *shoppingList* array are observable:

```
document.addEventListener('addItem',function(data) {
  document.querySelector('shop-cart').push('shoppingList', data.detail);
});
```